# Nvidia Graphics card not detected... After disabling it..?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I had installed the graphics card drivers and all when installing the OS. Everything was fine until my laptop started to switch off due to heating issues due to nvidia graphics card.... So I somehow disabled* it in a way i dont remember... Now `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` returns

```
omsk@omsk-Latitude-E6420:~/Desktop$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

It is just not able to detect the card... N now I have fixed the heating issue so i want to re enable it..

I have a Dell Latitude e6420 having a nvidia nvs 4200m.

I m on ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be preferable if you remember what you did and where but here are some suggestions: First check UEFI in case that's where you somehow disable it. If not there then open Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: If it was me I'd look in command `history`  for clues as to what I did (did you use commands?) or if you made package changes in apt logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) for details of what you did.. etc.  Given you've not yet told us what OS & release you are using, we know almost nothing about what you did.

Comment: @guiverc I m in ubuntu 20.04